# Entity Key Property Validation in Dynamic Data Entities Web Application on Insert Page Template

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Application with Scaffolding.
The scaffolding, Page Templates viz. Insert. Edit, Details, List, Entity Template Web User Controls all are working fine.

BUT my problem is, I want to Validate Primary Key during Insertion operation.
Say now If i left the Primary Key Field blank it validates with required field validator, same way I want to validate for Duplicate Entry in Primary  Key Field.

I even tried Custom Validator in Data Model, but unable to find proper solution for the same.

Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you told me you are using MVC, We have an **Remote** Validation in MVC which we can apply in our **Model Class Properties**.

Let me show you how:

```
[Required]
[Remote("IsUserIDExist", "Account", ErrorMessage = "User ID Already Exist")]
[Display(Name = "Enter User ID")]
public string User_username { get; set; }
```

This is my Property which is in **Account.cs** Model Class.

**IsUserIDExist** is the Action in  **Account** Controller.

Now let me show you **IsUserIDExist** Action.

```
public ActionResult IsDomainIDExist(string User_username)
{
    var users = from s in db.CreateUsers
                where s.User_username == User_username
                select s;
       if (users != null)
       {
         if (users.Count() != 0)
         {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
         }
         else
         {
           return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
          }
       }
       else
        {
          return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

This Code speaks it self.I guess there is no need for any explanation.

Last but not least.

You need to add these javascript files to work with Remote Validation

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.json-2.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: **Sorry yaar Rahul, I was confused differentiating MVC & Non-MVC.. please provide me solution for non-MVC.... 
THANKS A LOT.. If nothing works then I shall implement this MVC enabled